# Comparing raw object with a Stack/Queue - Overriding equals() method

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, queue

I've created a class which can be inherited to create both a Stack and a Queue using  LinkedLists, I've passed all the JUnit tests except the equals one, I still have no idea why it doesn't work.

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if( o == null) return false;
    if(o == this) return true;


    if(!(o instanceof PushPop)) return false;
    PushPop test1= this;
    PushPop test = (PushPop)o;
    while(!test.isEmpty() && !test1.isEmpty()){
        if(test1.pop() != test.pop()) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The test sends out an assertion error whenever it's comparing the values, specifically whenever a  stack/queue  has an extra value than the second one.

Comment: you are modifying your stacks during `equals`. In fact you are clearing them. Do you see how this could be a problem?

Comment: I'm modifying the stacks as I need to compare all of the objects and I have no other way than popping each element and comparing it with the other stacks popped element.

I'm supposed to check if the items are the same and in the same order, although you do have a point. I should create a copy of the original so it doesn't get modified.

I've edited the code to add the copy of the data structure.

Comment: See if that fixes your problem... I see you running the same test twice and it just returning `true` the second time because they're both empty

Comment: It didn't work, it's still sending out an AssertionError. 

And excuse me? I don't understand which tests you're talking about

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't exactly clear. I meant "I imagine you running..."

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError
at edd.test. TestStack.testEquals(TestStack.java)

The third line is the one which marks the error  
 for (int i = 0; i < total; 
            stack.push(i);
            Assert.assertFalse(stack.equals(stack2));
            stack2.push(i);
            Assert.assertTrue(stack.equals(stack2));
        }

Comment: Can you post the code of your test?

Comment: @Test public void testEquals() {
        Assert.assertFalse(stack.equals(null));
        Assert.assertFalse(stack.equals(""));
        stack<Integer> stack2 = new stack<Integer>();
        Assert.assertTrue(stack.equals(stack2));
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
         
            stack.push(i);
            Assert.assertFalse(stack.equals(stack2));
            stack2.push(i);
            Assert.assertTrue(stack.equals(stack2));
        }
    }

Comment: does `stack` extend `PushPop`?

Comment: Yes, so does Queue. The only thing different between those classes is the insertion method.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have located your problem:

In your test, you do the following [taken from comment]

```
stack.push(i);
Assert.assertFalse(stack.equals(stack2));
stack2.push(i);
Assert.assertTrue(stack.equals(stack2));
```

This seems reasonable. However, `equals` clears both stacks so when you `push` `i` onto `stack2`, it is no longer equal to the now-empty `stack`.

Hence your error.

The solution: **Don't Modify Your Object In An `equals` Method.**

I'd suggest cloning or comparing whatever your underlying data structure is (e.g., if you're using Nodes, having `Node` implement `equals`).

Comment: I'm not supposed to modify the Test, it's given out by my teacher.

I did notice it runs fine whenever I delete that line... 

So in the end the tests have a mistake or do I still have an error?

Comment: I'm not suggesting modifying the test. You need to fix your `equals`

Comment: Thank you, I already fixed it. 

I added another condition, it checked the size of the stack and compared it with the size of the second stack.

That seemed to fix it.  
Thanks for your input, it helped me review my code. 
In the end I shouldn't be programming at 1 am.